# Looking for a film with a group stranded on an island

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a film I saw in around 2000. I would guess it was made around 1990, but could be as early as 1980.

It features:

A group of people stranded on an island

Near the beginning one of more of the group were in the sea and attacked by a creature in it

Later they were in an abandonded building, large, probably a factory or warehouse and I think something chased them in there and they locked themselves in a room

Near the end I think they encountered some sort of tribe, or people, and one of the men was in a building, I think, a hut, with one of the tribe's women. She did something like attack him and I believe she had the ability to shapeshift

Comment: do you recall how big the group was, or any descriptions of them? genders? colors? anything unique about any of them?

Comment: Sounds as any number of those bad SyFy made-for-TV movies that are a dime a dozen. So... was in on TV or in an actual movie theatre?

Comment: I saw it on TV; it did seem like it was a lower budget film, but I liked it at the time. As for the group, I think it was somewhere in the region between 10-12, and I don't remember there being any non-white people, almost certainly they were a majority of whites. I think there was a man who was the leader of the group who looked a bit like: http://extras.mnginteractive.com/live/media/site568/2013/0925/20130925_083110_revolution-1.jpg from what I remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like a 1992 movie that was called "The presence" and also known as  [Danger island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_Island_(film)).  I saw it on TV years ago, it seems like it was supposed to be a pilot.

> A group of people stranded on an island.

There was a plane crash and the survivors floated to an island.

> Near the beginning one of more of the group were in the sea and
>   attacked by a creature in it

When trying to escape the island, they were attacked by a tentacle monster.

> Later they were in an abandonded building, large, probably a factory
>   or warehouse and I think something chased them in there and they
>   locked themselves in a room

There was a biological weapons research facility on the island, and the island was full of dangerous products of said facility.  One of the characters mutates and becomes dangerous and chases them through the facility.

> Near the end I think they encountered some sort of tribe, or people,
>   and one of the men was in a building, I think, a hut, with one of the
>   tribe's women. She did something like attack him and I believe she had
>   the ability to shapeshift

There was a tribe on the island.  When one character is getting intimate with an indigenous woman, he hallucinates that she is shapeshifting due to being poisoned by some local plant life.

Turns out you can watch the whole thing on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vL0hQ5mLi50) as well.

Comment: The net ripples as Barnoet Canid puts one away.

Comment: Haha, I had not realized this was two years old until after I answered it.  Thanks for coming back to mark it as answered Kohjah.