# Movie or miniseries about people shipwrecked on an island with an abandoned military facility and Aborigines

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

It was about some shipwrecked survivors. They get onto an island and one man is attacked in the water by something you can't see. Later at night he begins to mutate and goes to the sea. Then the other survivors find this abandoned military facility. They find Aborigines and they gave some bananas to the survivors, and the bananas began to swell while everyone is sleeping. I remember watching this in the '90s.

Comment: You have capitalised "Aborigines" as a term - do you mean indigenous Australians, or do you mean aboriginal inhabitants of some unspecified island?  Also, what era was this set in?

Comment: the second one, sorry but English is not my primary language, anyway Baronet_Canid found the movie I was looking for, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of a pilot called "The Presence", also called "Danger island".  It was made in 1992, and hits those story beats, although I don't remember the bananas swelling.  Check this similar question that has a better more complete [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106233/looking-for-a-film-with-a-group-stranded-on-an-island/171782#171782).

You can watch the whole movie on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vL0hQ5mLi50), and check if it matches your memories.

Comment: Oh my god, I've been looking for this movie for many years and no one remembered it, thank you very very much.

Comment: Glad to help! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted?